# Print out all the instances of a particular token type

Tags: bison

After running `yyparse` I'd like to print out all of the `VARNAME`s found in the input. I don't know enough about the internals of the yacc variables to know where to look, and google isn't turning up anything obvious.

I could modify the bison rule to keep track of these using C vars as the tokens come in one by one, but for code clarity reasons it would be much better if all of this could be done in one shot after the parse.

basic.l:

```
[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*\$? {
          yylval.s = yytext;
          return VARNAME;
}
```

basic.y:

```
%union {
  double d;
  GString *s;
}
%token <s> VARNAME

variable: VARNAME
{
  variable_t *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
  new->name = $1;
  $$ = new;
}
```

Comment: Returning yytext like this from the lexer is unsafe, as it will only be valid until the next token is read (and bison might need to read ahead a token before reducing and running the action).  You should allocate the `variable_t` in the lexer and copy yytext into it there.

Comment: Is the issue the yytext? If so, would a strcpy fix it? Or is the problem on the yylval side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither (f)lex nor yacc/bison makes any attempt to save tokens after they have been consumed (by a reduction action). If you want to save them, you need to do that yourself.

I usually do it in the lexer, by adding each ID token into an interned string table (i.e. a hash set). That makes storage management easier because I can just delete all the strings from the hash table when the parse is done. It also avoids needless copies of duplicate strings.

Note that you cannot safely use `yytext` in yacc/bison actions; so if your parser needs to refer to the text value of a token which has more than one possible string value, your scanner must make (or reuse) a copy of the contents of `yytext`.

If the code in your scanner was copied from some (f)lex file you found on the internet, I'd strongly recommend that you find a different model. The code almost certainly does not work, so it indicates that no non-trivial testing was ever done.

Comment: "by adding each ID token into an interned string table:" - fair enough!